# Trying to find a specific synonym for "aforementioned"

Tags: synonyms

It's used sort of like:

> The [aformentioned] *Jack Box* of Jack in The Box is the mascot of the Jack in The Box fast food restaurant franchise.

In my mind, it's used to denote a word that exists within the title of its origin. I haven't been able to find it on thesaurus.com.

Comment: Do you mean, instead, *eponymous*? "Of, relating to, or being the person or thing for whom or which something is named : of, relating to, or being an eponym // … Ramayana, an Indian epic which chronicles, in sixty thousand verses, the adventures of its **eponymous** hero Rama … — Leila Hadley, *Give Me the World*, (1958) 1999" [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponymous)

Comment: That's not what _aforementioned_ means. You would only use it if 'Jack Box' had been _mentioned before_  in the text.

Comment: Or *titular* which isn't as nice-sounding as *eponymous*.

Comment: Might the reason you haven't been able to find it on thesaurus.com be that 'it's used to denote a word that exists within the title of its origin…' has no clear meaning? 

Most obviously 'The [aformentioned]…' might be 'The said…'

Does that work for you?